# Remove start of lines with sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have list in the file called `name.txt` with these strings:

```
Los Angeles, CA us1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Washington, DC  us2.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Austin, TX  us3.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Miami, FL   us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com
New York City, NY   us5.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Chicago, IL us6.vpn.goldenfrog.com
San Francisco, CA   us7.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Amsterdam   eu1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Copenhagen  dk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Stockholm   se1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
Hong Kong   hk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
London  uk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
```

Now I want with sed delete everything before `*.vpn.goldenfrog.com` (where `*` is three characters).

The output I want:

```
hk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
dk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
etc ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/\1/' file.txt
```

The captured group (`\1`) will contain the portion of the line after last space, we are using that in the replacement.

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/\1/' file.txt  
us1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us2.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us3.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us5.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us6.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us7.vpn.goldenfrog.com
eu1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
dk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
se1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
hk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
uk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
```

---

`grep` can easily do this too:

```
% grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*$' file.txt                   
us1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us2.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us3.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us5.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us6.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us7.vpn.goldenfrog.com
eu1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
dk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
se1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
hk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
uk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
```

Comment: This sed solution can be simplified. There is no need to capture anything. Simply match everything up to and including the final blank and replace it with nothing: `s/.*[[:blank:]]//`

Answer (score 3):

if it doesn't have to be `sed`, `awk` is just cut out for this process:

```
awk '{print $NF}' filename
```

Comment: Thats cool , Can explain me {print $NF} exactly what do ?

Comment: NF stands for **number of fields** on a given line or string, which references the last field on the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file is space-delimited, you may simply delete the contents of each line up until the last space character:

```bash
$ sed 's/.* //' file
us1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us2.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us3.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us5.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us6.vpn.goldenfrog.com
us7.vpn.goldenfrog.com
eu1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
dk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
se1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
hk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
uk1.vpn.goldenfrog.com
```

If the file uses tabs as the delimiter, you may use `[[:blank:]]` in place of the literal space character in the expression.  This would match a tab *or* a space character:

```bash
sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]//' file
```

You could also get the last tab-delimited field with `cut` by first reversing each line, and then reversing the result of cutting out the 1st field:

```bash
rev file | cut -f 1 | rev
```

If the data has exactly two tab-delimited fields and you want the 2nd of these, then it's even simpler:

```bash
cut -f 2 file
```